# Trying to make a polygon responsive in DIV

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, points

I've been searching for hours but I can't seem to find a fix for my problem, I want to make a triangle which is responsive to the DIV it is in, it also has to have the full width of the div. The div has position relative but no matter what I try, the polygon always seems to overflow the div or get out of place.

Eventually the responsive polygon has to go above the 'something' button, but let's first try to fix the current problem.

Recap: the triangle needs to be responsive with the main div as it changes size without overflowing or getting a different shape, the triangle has to be 100% the width of the div.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8gv17c2/1/

HTML:

```
    <div class="row events">
    <div class="onebyone">
        <div class="onebytext">
            <div class="textInfo">Test</div>
        </div>
            <div class="triangle">
                <svg data-type="vertical_parallax" data-speed="2" x="0px" y="0px" width="410" height="410" viewBox="0 0 310 310">
                    <polyline fill="#CC0000" points="0,0 0,200 300,0"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="onebysign">
                <button class="submitBtn">Something</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
      font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color:#f2f2f2;
    }
    .events{
      padding:20px 100px;
    }
    .textInfo{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
      color:#085DAD;
      padding:10px;
      background-color:white;
    }
    .onebyone {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
      position: relative; /* If you want text inside of it */
      background-size:cover;
    }
    .onebytext{
      position:  absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
        font-size:32px;
      color: white;
      width:90%;
      left:5%;
    }
    .onebysign{
      position:  absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color:white;
        font-size:24px;
    }
    .onebytext, .onebysign{
      position:  absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .submitBtn{
      background-color:#0099CC;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding:10px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      border:0px;
      width:70%;
      margin:10px 0;

    }
    .triangle {
      width: 100%;
      height: 4px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: If the polygon has one aspect ratio and the div has another how can it keep the full width of the div unless it either a) overflows or b) distorts to match the aspect ratio of the container?

Comment: @RobertLongson So you're basically saying that I have to match the aspect ratio's of the polygon and the div?

Comment: If the div is 10 units wide by 1 unit high and the polygon's natural shape is 1 unit by 1 unit. How do you want it to scale up? If we make it 10 units by 10 units it will overflow. If we make it 10 units by 1 unit it will distort. Which do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for this:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 40%;
}

.triangle svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8gv17c2/3/

Simply change the width of the parent to adjust the width of the `<svg>` (responsively): https://jsfiddle.net/L8gv17c2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Insert a height of 100% in your **.triangle** class and put **max-width** and **max-height** to your svg:

```
.triangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

svg {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L8gv17c2/2/)